# Can once use pct_change() over index value?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

If there are multi-index columns in a dataframe, is it possible to use pct_change over one of the index columns? In this particular case `day` must remain an index column.

I tried using `data['pc_day'] = data['day'].pct_change()` where `day` is a index column. I know this would not work because data['day'] is treating it like a non-index column.

i got the following error: `KeyError: 'day'`

Can it be done without creating another column called day and doing pct_change on that?

Comment: It might help if you provide an MRE.

Comment: I dont know what MRE means?

Comment: Minimal reproducible example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example